thrust::inner_product is very slow on thrust::device_vector
When I try to use thrust::inner_product with thrust::device_vector it works very slow.
See the test:
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int vec_size = 1000000;
    const int iterations = 10000;

    float milliseconds = 0;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    thrust::host_vector<float> host_x(vec_size);
    thrust::generate(host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), rand);

    thrust::host_vector<float> host_y(vec_size);
    thrust::generate(host_y.begin(), host_y.end(), rand);

    printf("vector size = %lu floats\n", vec_size);

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    thrust::device_vector<float> device_x = host_x;
    thrust::device_vector<float> device_y = host_y;
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("copy (device)\t\t%f ms\n", milliseconds);

    float gpu_sum = 0.0f;

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        gpu_sum += thrust::inner_product(device_x.begin(), device_x.end(), device_y.begin(), 0.0f);
    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("inner_product (device)\t%f ms\n", milliseconds / iterations);

    float cpu_sum = 0.0f;

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        cpu_sum += thrust::inner_product(thrust::host, host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), host_y.begin(),0.0f);
    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("inner_product (host)\t%f ms\n", milliseconds / iterations);

    std::cout << "GPU sum = " << gpu_sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "CPU sum = " << cpu_sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I get the following results on the AMD Ryzen 9 3950X + NVIDIA RTX2080 Super (Release settings, device: compute_75,sm_75.):
inner.exe 3100000 1000
vector size = 24800000 bytes
copy (device)           6.553728 ms
inner_product (device)  0.503536 ms
inner_product (host)    0.000006 ms

So, CPU does this in no time, while device spends significant time.
My actual code confirms the same results, any attempts to use thrust::device_vector with thrust::inner_product lead to dramatic slowdown.
Am I wrong with something here or this is not the way to use thrust library today and such tasks should be solved with CUDA/CUB, etc.?
Note
Actually, I got absolutely the same problem as discussed in 10 years old question
Thrust Complex Inner Product Run on GPU Slower Than STL Implementation on CPU, but in my case the results on CUDA 12.5 is much worse.
At that time the problem was solved, so my case have the same symptoms, but for sure will have different causes and solution (after all that question/answer related to too old versions).
Update
I found the root cause. It is related to the amount of calls thrust::inner_product or to the size of the processed batch, to be more specific.
Here are the results for some sizes for the code above:



vec_size(floats)
Device
Host




100
0.030 ms
0.000062 ms


1’000
0.031 ms
0.000730 ms


10’000
0.068 ms
0.007ms


100’000
0.081 ms
0.070 ms


1’000’000
0.37 ms
0.71 ms



So, based on this, every call to thrust::inner_product if executed on device, costs 0.03 ms which is much larger than processing time until the batch size gets to 100’000 elements or more.
Since my vectors were about 20 elements, performance degradation was about 3000 times and I didn’t expect to have this for the data allocated on device (GPU). I was sure that the call itself should be significantly cheaper. Indeed, getting benefits only from 100’000 on high-end GPU against single-threaded CPU version makes arguable profits from such approach.
If I got the wrong end of the stick, please let me know. I was sure thrust is faster than that.

You are not using the result of inner_product, so the compiler is free to optimize the host version away. The host compiler is not able to look at the kernel code, so it can't optimize away the kernel launch.

Using CUB directly can be better as it allows to keep the result in device memory and is more flexible regarding synchronization. But I would not expect a giant difference as the kernel should be the same.

You should be using the code posted in Robert Crovella's answer to the linked old question where you got your code. The google-benchmark library has tools for avoiding this kind of optimization (maybe sth similar can be achieved using the volatile keyword).

@paleonix, thank you so much for catching this! Worked like a charm. After avoiding CPU optimization I get device code executed 6 times faster than host code. Anyway, my actual code which uses the resulting values are dramatically slower with thrust. Working now on porting it to performance test as minimal reproducible example and will update the question soon (in case I don't find solution during the porting).

Slower than what? Using the CPU for the inner product? Is the data resident on the GPU?

@paleonix, in my actual code inner_product on CPU is much faster than inner_product on GPU (for floats). Data resident in GPU (stored in thrust::device_vector as here in the question). The problem could be that I invoke it many times and update one of the vectors stored on GPU (which in profiler don't show much issue). When I click Pause in VS2022 while running the code it catches thrust::inner_product mostly in some kind of sync operation in implementation (ntdll.dll!RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive).

In that case CUB might actually be the solution as written above. Could it be possible to merge these many launches into one algorithm? I recommend taking a look at the Nsight Systems (nsys) trace.

@paleonix, I finally found the root cause. I've updated the code to avoid optimizations and to get the stats that I need to show the root cause. To put in a nutshell, every call to thrust::inner_product takes 0.03 ms, which makes its use for batches smaller than 100'000 floats counterproductive. Please check if my findings are correct or if I made another mistake (like I did with CPU optimization).

20 elements is just way too small for the GPU to shine. How many of these 20 element reductions are there and can they be done in parallel?

@paleonix, there are about 100000 reductions with average size of 24 elements and they are called in parallel from 16 core CPU with std::for_each/par_unseq. I understand that 20 elements way too few. I just never expected that even 10000 in one batch would be counter-productive with batches in GPU memory. Seems thrust is not a way to go here. I have lots of code which works fine with thrust, was just interested to make this working, as well. Will move all this part to CUDA (or CUB/cuBLAS).

@paleonix, by the way, are you aware if cuBLAS is a part of CUB (like its linear library) or they are standalone libraries? Can't see this from the documentation at a first glance. My code was for multi-agent feed forward neural network, so I have thousands small networks with few small layers. What approach would you recommend for these calculations? Of course, pure CUDA would be the best, I am just looking for a way to reuse some library, especially since some day I would need backpropagation algorithms.

cuBLAS and CUB are unrelated. cuBLAS is Nvidia's proprietary dense linear algebra library with C-API while CUB is their open source header-only C++ library of parallel primitives at device, block or warp scope. Recently Thrust, CUB and libcu++ were bundled into one big project/repository called CCCL.

thrust::reduce_by_key (or its CUB equivalent) might be of interest if all these small vectors are actually one big buffer.

You definitely need to process this stuff in batches. Allocate the same layer in each agent in a combined buffer and do one call for all. Whether that's a library or a custom kernel will need testing because for best performance, you want a kernel that handles a full vector in a single warp, not thread block or larger. Without testing, it will probably not be obvious if a library does that. Therefore I'd always write a custom kernel, even if it is just for comparison.

@paleonix, thank you. Are you sure thrust::reduce_by_key could help here? My problem is that I need to multiply values first and then add up them (doing this for many input vectors), so the only good choice I have is to create zip_iterator for two input ranges, but reduce_by_key requires consistency of types for binary_op (inputs and outputs have to be tuples, then). In this case, the result will be a tuple with extra dummy element with a memory footprint. If I am wrong and you see the way to use it, please let me know, I will create a separate question on that.

@Homer512, thank you for the input. Yes, I see now that going without batching is out of the question. Of course, I will implement CUDA kernel for this as a basis for further performance comparisons. My adherence to thrust is due to large amount of thrust code which worked just fine and saved me a lot of time, so I took a challenge to apply thrust here since I was sure that it is just a lack of my experience with it which is in my way here. It seems it is a good time to give up and use tool appropriate for the task instead of sticking to one. Thank you for reminding about the balance here.

Well, inner_product is basically just a special case of transform_reduce. While there is no transform_reduce_by_key, it can be easily emulated using a transform_iterator.

@paleonix, thank you, now I can multiply/add in batches. My next problem is that calculating the next layer values I need to multiply each row (weights) by the same column of previous layer (values); so, I have to use this column many times (vector/matrix multiplication). With the thrust::transform_reduce_by_key I have to duplicate this vector or make as many calls as rows in the matrix. If only I could explain to algorithm that the shorter vector (column) should be used “in loop”, starting from the beginning when it ends, but I don’t see any way to do so. Any hints for this step?

I think matrix-vector multiplication is really a point where STL/Thrust doesn't make sense. There is a reason why there are plans to have BLAS in the C++ standard library and why there are many CUDA libraries (cuBLAS, CUTLASS, cuTensor, ...) specialized just to BLAS/tensors etc. If you dislike the C APIs, maybe MatX is of interest but I have not used it myself. It tries to bring sth like Numpy with CUDA acceleration to C++.
